# Problem with Authlogic and Unit/Functional Tests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, authlogic

I'm learning how unit testing is done in Rails, and I've run into a problem involving Authlogic.

According to the [Documentation](http://rdoc.info/rdoc/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/f2f6988d3b97e11770b00b72a7a9733df69ffa5b/Authlogic/TestCase.html) there are a few things required to use Authlogic stuff in your tests:

test_helper.rb:

```
require "authlogic/test_case"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup :activate_authlogic
end
```

Then in my functional tests I can login users:

```
UserSession.create(users(:tester))
```

The problem seems to stem from the `setup :activate_authlogic` line in test_helper.rb, whenever that is included, I get the following errors when running functional tests:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `request=' for nil:NilClass
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/controller_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:63:in `send'
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/controller_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:63:in `method_missing'
```

If I remove `setup :activate_authlogic` and add instead `Authlogic::Session::Base.controller = Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::RailsAdapter.new(self)` to test_helper.rb, my functional tests seem to work but now my unit tests fail:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `params' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/controller_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:30:in `params'
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/session/params.rb:96:in `params_credentials'
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/session/params.rb:72:in `params_enabled?'
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/session/params.rb:66:in `persist_by_params'
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:79:in `persist'
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/session/persistence.rb:55:in `persisting?'
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/session/persistence.rb:39:in `find'
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/session_maintenance.rb:96:in `get_session_information'
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/session_maintenance.rb:95:in `each'
    authlogic (2.1.3) lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/session_maintenance.rb:95:in `get_session_information'
    /test/unit/user_test.rb:23:in `test_should_save_user_with_email_password_and_confirmation'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the setup :activate_authlogic class in your unit test class and not in the ActiveSupport::TestCase declaration in test_helper.

e.g.

```
class ExampleControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    setup :activate_authlogic
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to include the Authlogic test case module like this in order to get things working.

```
class ExampleControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    include Authlogic::TestCase
    setup :activate_authlogic
end
```

I'm not sure why Authlogic wouldn't include itself on my system... but the code (in authlogic/test_case) doesn't work on my system:

```
::Test::Unit::TestCase.send(:include, TestCase) if defined?(::Test::Unit::TestCase)
```

Comment: I also had to require 'authlogic/test_case', but there may be something wonky with my setup.

Answer (score 3):

http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/TestCase

evertything is very well described on the link above.

Answer (score 2):

The setup :authlogic line needs to be in the ActionController::TestCase class, not the ActiveSupport::TestCase.

Inside your test_helper, put this in:

```
  class ActionController::TestCase
    setup :activate_authlogic
  end
```